# Java Multipart/post download

Tags: java, http, apache-httpclient-4.x

I have few questions related to web technologies. From my reading ant looking at Apache and Netty documents I could not figure out few things about downloading a large file with HTTP multipart/post request.

1. Is it possible to send HTTP request indicating request to download a file in smaller multipart (chunks)?
2. How to download large file in multipart ?

Please correct me if I have not understood the 'multipart' term itself. I know lot of people have faced this problem, where application (client) downloads files in smaller portion, so when network outage happens, application does not need to download whole file from the beginning again. Specially, when the file is not any media file.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Multipart refers to encoding multiple documents in one body, see [this](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc1341/7_2_Multipart.html) for the definition.  For http, a multipart upload allows the client to send multiple documents with one post, for example uploading an image, and form fields in one request.

Multipart does not refer to downloading a document in multiple chunks.

You can use [http ranges](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.35) to restart downloading if a network outage occurs.